# Maintaining total count of a set in another collection

Tags: mongodb

I got simple scenario of two entities: post; bumps (ie upvote).

Example of a post:

```
{_id: 'happy_days', 'title': 'Happy days', text: '...', bumps: 2}
```

Example of a bump:

```
{_id: {user: 'jimmy', post: 'happy_days'}}
{_id: {user: 'hans', post: 'happy_days'}}
```

**Question: how do I maintain correct `bumps` count in post under all circumstances (and failures)?**

The method I have come up with so far is:

- To bump, upsert and check for existence. Only if inserted, increase `bumps` count.
- To unbump, delete and check for existence. Only if deleted, decrease `bumps` count.

Above fails if the app crashes between the two ops and the only way to correct the bumps stats is to query all documents in bump collection and recalculate everything offline (ie there is no way to know which post have incorrect bumps count).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you stick with what you already have. The worst that can happen if there is a failover/connection issue between your two operations is that you bump count is wrong. So what? This is not the end of the world, and nobody is going to care too much if a bump count is either 812 or 813. You can always recreate the count anyway by checking how many bumps you have for each post by running an aggregation query **if** something went wrong. Embrace eventual consistency!

Comment: One great thing that came to me yesterday was the use of limits within the signature of the $inc operator to stop counters from expiring below 0 etc etc, unfortunately it was classed as part of a bigger and more...unweidly JIRA of conditional querying. Though I still think it was a good idea

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to updating the data in multiple places (which, for read performance, will probably be the best but as you noticed will complicate updates) it may be worth considering storing uid's of the bumps in an array (here called bump_uids) directly on the post, and just count the bumps when needed using aggregate framework;

```js
> db.test.aggregate( [ { $match: { _id:'happy_days' } },
                       { $project: { bump_uids: 1 } },
                       { $unwind: '$bump_uids' }, 
                       { $group: {_id:'$_id', bumps: { $sum:1 } } } ] )

>>> { "result" : [ { "_id" : "happy_days", "bumps" : 3 } ], "ok" : 1 }
```

Comment: The bumps for a post can grow to set of thousand elements. Putting the space issues aside (ie can easily hit the 16MB on a single doc limit), not sure how efficient the aggregate op performs on even a hundred elements.

Answer (score 0):

Since MongoDB does not yet support triggers ( https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-124 ) you have to do this the gritty way with application logic.

As a brief example:

```
db.follower.insert({fromId:u,toId:c});
db.user.update({_id:u},{$inc:{totalFollowing:1}});
db.user.update({_id:c},{$inc:{totalFollowers:1}});
```

Yes, it is not atomic etc etc however it is the way to do it. In reality many update counters like this, whether in MongoDB or not.